Windows 11 freezes on boot
My Windows 11 installation, that worked before, started having an issue where pressing on the start or search buttons on the taskbar would cause windows explorer to crash, I tried running sfc /scannow and chkdsk /r /f, but after a restart explorer crashes constantly and some apps have issues. I then tried entering WinRE and safe mode, but it failed booting and now the Windows 11 Installation Media and Windows 11 get stuck on the boot screen, although the Windows 10 Installation Media works. Could someone PLEASE help me??? I have dual boot with linux, if that helps. A way to remove the boot into safe mode and WinRE option from linux, perhaps from editing a file in windows would be amazing.

Also, a way to stop booting into WinRE and safe mode without access to the desktop would be nice.

Dual boot neither helps nor is it in any way, shape or form relevant for the problem of Windows installation media getting stuck. First advice is redo that media properly - and no, you can't do it from Linux unless you use Ventoy or MKUSB - and try again.

@ChanganAuto I used Ventoy and it failed

How exactly did it fail? Did you see the Ventoy (Grub) menu, selected Windows and it didn't boot, or it booted but apparently "frooze" in the dots circle, or nothing of the above? Are you sure 1. Ventoy was correctly installed, 2. the ISO file isn't corrupt and was correctly copied to the root of the flash drive? Also, does it work correctly in Linux? Please always [edit] the question to add requested info and/or clarification, not just comments. Namely describe *exactly what happens when you try to boot the installation media.

“Could someone PLEASE help me?” - Sure; Replace the storage device and reinstall Windows.

Luckily, the Windows 11 Installation Media works in wimboot mode.

Perform a Repair Install of Windows by downloading the Windows install ISO, extracting it to a directory, and launching setup.exe while booted to Windows, choosing to keep all files and settings. Afterwards, you may have to repair GRUB.

Note: This question should be closed as OP notes they will resolve things by backing up and reinstalling Windows. As such, the situation cannot be replicated and so a true solution can no longer be found.

Windows 10 WHQL support had to be set to UEFI instead of CSM in the BIOS.
